# React multi select dropdown

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I am having an issue with my select dr. The value are not showing up. I also want them to be able to choose the corresponding column.

`````
const [valueState, setValueState] = useState('');

       const filterOptions = [
         { value: '', label: 'Select a column' },
         { value: 'all', label: 'All' },
         { value: 'first_name', label: 'First Name' },
         { value: 'last_name', label: 'Last Name' },
         { value: 'email', label: 'Email' },
         { value: 'title', label: 'Title' },

       const handler = (event) => {
         const { value } = event;
         setValueState(value);
         };````

    <SelectBox
           value=""
           defaultValue=""
           placeholder="Select columns"
           isMulti
           options={filterOptions}
           onChange={handler}
           name="ColumnSelect"
           label=""
           isClearable
         />
`````

Comment: It is hard to understand your problem. More code would help. I see you are trying to access `filterOptions.value` however filterOptions is an array of objects. You need to mutate a state variable in order to tell the dr which is the current value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this change

```js
//create a state to store the value
const [valueState, setValueState] = useState('');

//handler function
const handleSelectChange = (value) => {
  setValueState(value);
}

// change your `value` & `onChange` prop
<SelectBox
       value={valueState}
       defaultValue=""
       placeholder="Select columns"
       isMulti
       options={filterOptions}
       onChange={ (value) => handleSelectChange(value) }
       name="ColumnSelect"
       label=""
       isClearable
/>
```